# flutter could not find image file in pubspec.yaml

Tags: flutter

Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Error detected in pubspec.yaml:
No file or variants found for asset: image/diamond.png.

I am getting error when running main.dart.   I tried checking the pubspec.yaml file but could not find any indenting issue.  i don't know why andriod studio cannot find the file in the image folder.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 896
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 17s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: can you send asset location

Answer (score 0):

Have you deleted an image called diamond.png in asset folder. It seems some place, your code is still using the deleted image, and hence cannot be build.

Also check pubspec.yaml for any reference to the same. If so clear it, and rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

You may have your pubspec not structured correctly

If file tree is

```
myApp
 - lib
 - android
 - ios
 - pubspec.yaml
 - assets
    - diamond.png
  ...
```

pubspec.yaml

```
name: my_app
version: 0.0.1
...
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/diamond.png
```